# Need to switch on a 120V pump with a 48V circuit. Relay? Solenoid? Not Possible?

Tags: solenoid

I am new to relays, etc.

Situation:

I have a 48V air conditioner on my boat that must be supplied with cooling water from a 120V water pump. The water pump is a completely separate unit. The air conditioner has a 48V output that is energized when the AC is running. This is supposed to be the signal to turn on the pump. When the AC turns off, the output is de-energized.

The pump wiring (AC) is 100 percent separate.

Question: Is there a solenoid/relay that can be supplied with 48V DC to then complete the 120V circuit AC pump circuit?

Comment: How much current does the pump use?

Comment: Which pump is it (make/model, specs)?

Comment: You need a 48 V pump, dude.   You have the very real possibility of the A/C calling for circulation water and the 120V *just not being there* because of whatever.  Eliminate that failure mode by running the pump on 48V.

Comment: Thanks! Pump model is Iwaki 15MD--It's only supposed to pull .3 apms @115V.

Comment: I would prefer a 48V pump but I just can't find one in the size I need.

Answer (score 1):

For a normally-open type relay one applies voltage to its coil in order to cause the contacts to close.

There is no reason that the coil and contact voltages need to be the same.  Its certainly possible to have a relay with contacts rated for 120V and a coil rated for any number of other voltages including 3V, 5V, 12V, 24V, or 48V.

One example would be something like the [J115F31C48VDCS.9](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cit-relay-and-switch/J115F31C48VDCS-9/14001855)

It takes a 48V DC coil voltage and can switch AC loads up to 277V AC and 40A.

There are many other similar options from distributors like [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-relays-over-2-amps/188) or [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/c/electromechanical/relays-contactors-solenoids/).

Comment: Idk if that relay is good for an inductive application like a pump.

Comment: at 40A and 277V it will probably work failry well assuming the load is significantly smaller

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's what relays do.  for switching motors a special type of relay called a contactor is normally used.

Comment: Is a contactor a more apropriate choice?

Comment: it depends on the pump, if it is a small motor the relay is probably sufficient. (and cheaper)

Comment: Thank you for the help!